# use array to iterate and parse other arrays CSV?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, csv

I've got a list of persons saved in an array and I want to loop a file with organizations looking for matches and save them but it keeps going wrong. I think I'm doing something wrong with the arrays.

This is exactly what I'm doing:

1. I have a list of persons in a file called 'personen_fixed.csv'.
2. I save that list into an array.
3. I have another file that also has the name of the people ("pers2"), but also three other interesting columns of data. I save the four columns into arrays.
4. I want to loop over the first array (the persons) and search for matches with the list of persons ("pers2").
5. If there is a match I want to save that row.

What I'm getting now is two rows of data, of which one is filled with ALL persons. See my code below. On the bottom i have some sample input data.

```
require 'csv'
array_pers1 = []
array_pers2 = []
array_orgaan = []
array_functie = []
array_rol = []

filename_1 = 'personen_fixed.csv'
CSV.foreach(filename_1, :col_sep => ";", :encoding => "windows-1251:utf-8", :return_headers => false) do |row|
  array_pers1 << row[0].to_s
end

filename_2 = 'Functies_fixed.csv'
CSV.foreach(filename_2, :col_sep => ";", :encoding => "windows-1251:utf-8", :return_headers => false) do |row|
  array_pers2 << row[1].to_s
  array_orgaan << row[16].to_s
  array_functie << row[17].to_s
  array_rol << row[18].to_s
end


CSV.open("testrij.csv", "w") do |row|
  row << ["rijnummer","link","ptext","soort_woonhuis"]

  for rij in array_pers1

    for x in 1...4426 do
      if rij === array_pers2["#{x}".to_f]
      pers2 = array_pers2["#{x}".to_f]
      orgaan = array_orgaan["#{x}".to_f]
      functie = array_functie["#{x}".to_f]
      rol = array_rol["#{x}".to_f]
      row << [pers2,orgaan,functie,rol]
      else 
      pers2 = ""
      orgaan = ""
      functie = ""
      rol = ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

input data for the first excel data (excel column name and first row of data):

```
person
someonesname
```

Input data for the second excel file:

```
person,organizationid,role,organization,function
someonesname,34971,member,americanairways,boardofdirectors
```

Since many of the people in the dataset have multiple jobs at different organizations, I want to save all them next to eachother (output I'm going for):

```
person,organization(1),function(1),role(1),organization(2),function(2),role(2) (max 5)
```

Comment: Provide sample input data and the expected output data.

Comment: I have (see below). Thanks for the tip Tin Man

Comment: Don't put required parts of your question in comments. Expecting potential answerers to comb the comments to piece the question and needed data together is asking an awful lot of the people trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of storing a single row from your Functies csv file in 4 separate arrays, and then combining them together later, so my answer doesn't tell you why your approach isn't working. Instead, I suggest a different approach that I believe is cleaner.

Building an array of names from the first file is ok. For the second file, I would store each row as an array and use a hash:

```
data = {
   "name1 => ["name1", "orgaan1", "functie1", "rol1"],
   "name2 => ["name2", "orgaan2", "functie2", "rol2"],
   ...
}
```

Building it might look like

```
data = {}
CSV.foreach(filename_2, :col_sep => ";", :encoding => "windows-1251:utf-8", :return_headers => false) do |row|
   name = row[1]
   orgaan = row[16]
   functie = row[17]
   rol = row[18]
   data[name] = [name, orgaan, functie, rol]
end
```

Then you would iterate over your first array and keep all the arrays that match

```
results = []
for name in array_pers1
  results << data[name] if data.include?(name)
end
```

---

On the other hand, if you don't want to use a hash and insist on using arrays (perhaps because names are not unique), I would still store them like

```
data = [
   ["name1", "orgaan1", "functie1", "rol1"],
   ["name2", "orgaan2", "functie2", "rol2"]
]
```

And then during your search step you would just iterate like

```
results = []
for name in array_pers1
   for row in data
      results << row if row[0] == name
   end
end
```

Comment: THanks Keikoku, that looks like it makes much more sense. However, how would I automatically fill the hash-array? (this one:
`data = {
   "name1 => ["name1", "orgaan1", "functie1", "rol1"],
   "name2 => ["name2", "orgaan2", "functie2", "rol2"],
   ...
}`

Comment: I've edited it to give an example of how you might build the hash when you're parsing your `filename_2`. Note that the hash approach assumes the names are unique, so the arrays might be better in that case.

Comment: The names are unique, so that's perfect. Thank you again Keikoku. It works perfectly if I just print out (puts) the results, but when i try to save it to a csv is still goes wrong.. 
`CSV.open("testrij.csv", "w") do |csv|
 csv << ["rijnummer","link","ptext","soort_woonhuis"]
 for name in array_pers1
  if data.include?(name)
   csv << data[name] 
  end
 end
end`
any thoughts on what kind of stupid mistake I'm making here? ;)

Comment: What goes wrong? An error occurs? The CSV file is produced incorrectly (values in the wrong columns, etc.)? Still getting two rows of data, where one row has all of the people?

Comment: Still getting two rows, where one row has all of the people / "the number of characters per cell has been exceeded"

Comment: Is it possible that you are loading an old file? I can't see anything wrong with the way you are writing to the CSV.